# How to test Nest.js GET request with multiple parameters in Postman?

Tags: postman, nestjs

I want to test a Get request that needs to filter my data, but I think I'm passing the parameters wrong. Here is the code:

```
//service that filter by sport and gender
async findSelectorsBySportGender(sportId: string, gend: string): Promise<Selector[]>
{
    return await this.selectorsRepository.find({where: {sport: {id: sportId}, gender: gend}, relations: ['sport','faculty']});
}

//controller
@Get()
 getSelectorsBySportGender(@Param('sport') sportId: string, @Param('gender')gender: string)
 {
     return this.selectorsService.findSelectorsBySportGender(sportId, gender);
 }

Get request in Postman:
http://localhost:3000/selectors?sportId=5f43c1ee-6be3-4881-913c-0aa89be49ae2&gender=female
```

Sport is foreign key, and it has id,name...I want to extract id to test the request. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Param` refers to path parameters, like `@Get('foo/:bar')` and then `@Param('bar') bar: string`

You're passing the values as [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) thus you should change those `Param` to `Query`.

https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#param-decorators

edit:

I just notice this: `sportId=...` thus the arg of `@Query` should be `'sportId'`, not `'sport'`. I you got it.

Comment: It still doesn't work properly. I think I'm passing the parameters wrong.

Comment: the url `http://localhost:3000/selectors?sportId=5f43c1ee-6be3-4881-913c-0aa89be49ae2&gender=female` is fine as long you use `@Query('sportId') sportId: string` Is that simple.